# Can I charge Android when it is uses OTG?

Tags: charging, usb-on-the-go

I want to have Android phone which talks with another device (that is Arduino but it's irrelevant to the question here) via USB OTG.

The problem I see is - I'd like the Android to be constantly charging. Is it possible?

It may be possible that I'm asking the same as here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/17329772/2401535
but my knowledge does not allow to assess that.

Comment: See also: [Can you use USB OTG and charge at the same time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194421/can-you-use-usb-otg-and-charge-at-the-same-time)

Comment: What phone are you talking about? is it an USB-C or a Micro-USB socket in the phone? Does the phone support USB-PD?

Comment: See also: [simultaneous USB-OTG and charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157856/simultaneous-usb-otg-and-charging)